# Why a distributed TensorFlow toy-example takes too long?

Tags: python, distributed-computing, tensorflow

I tried running to run a toy example for some matrix multiplication and addition using distributed TensorFlow.

My goal was to compute **`(A^n + B^n)`** where **`A[,]`** and **`B[,]`** are **`LxL`** matrices.

I used 2 machines on the public cloud to compute `A^n` on one machine and `B^n` on the second machine, than the addition again on the first machine.

When the machines had CPU only - my script worked great.
When both had GPU - It failed to run in a reasonable time! It had a huge latency...

**My question** - what did I do wrong in my script?

Note that for machine2 (`task:1`) I used `server.join()` and I used machine 1 (`task:0`) as the client in this with-in graph.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------
from zmq import Stopwatch; aClk_E2E = Stopwatch(); aClk_E2E.start()
#------------------------------------------------------------------
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import datetime

IP_1 = '10.132.0.2';     port_1 = '2222'
IP_2 = '10.132.0.3';     port_2 = '2222'

cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec( { "local": [ IP_1 + ":" + port_1,
                                             IP_2 + ":" + port_2
                                             ],
                                   }
                                )
server = tf.train.Server( cluster,
                          job_name   = "local",
                          task_index = 0
                          )
# server.join() # @machine2 ( task:1 )

n =    5
L = 1000  

def matpow( M, n ):
    if n < 1:                 # Abstract cases where n < 1
        return M
    else:
        return tf.matmul( M, matpow( M, n - 1 ) )

G = tf.Graph()

with G.as_default():
     with tf.device( "/job:local/task:1/cpu:0" ):
          c1 = []
          tB = tf.placeholder( tf.float32, [L, L] )     # tensor B placeholder
          with tf.device( "/job:local/task:1/gpu:0" ):
               c1.append( matpow( tB, n ) )

     with tf.device( "/job:local/task:0/cpu:0" ):
          c2 = []
          tA = tf.placeholder( tf.float32, [L, L] )     # tensor A placeholder
          with tf.device( "/job:local/task:0/gpu:0" ):
               c2.append( matpow( tA, n ) )
          sum2 = tf.add_n( c1 + c2 )
#---------------------------------------------------------<SECTION-UNDER-TEST>
t1_2 = datetime.datetime.now()
with tf.Session( "grpc://" + IP_1 + ":" + port_1, graph = G ) as sess:
     A = np.random.rand( L, L ).astype( 'float32' )
     B = np.random.rand( L, L ).astype( 'float32' )
     sess.run( sum2, { tA: A, tB: B, } )
t2_2 = datetime.datetime.now()
#---------------------------------------------------------<SECTION-UNDER-TEST>

#------------------------------------------------------------------
_ = aClk_E2E.stop()
#------------------------------------------------------------------
print( "Distributed Computation time: " + str(t2_2 - t1_2))
print( "Distributed Experiment  took: {0: > 16d} [us] End-2-End.".format( _ ) )
```

Comment: Would you mind to update your post with a quantitative statement, what is expected to be { ultra-low, adequate-enough, too large }-latency and what is expected to be { fast, adequately-enough, too slow }-processing for an explicitly given matrix-sizes 1E+{3,6,9} x 1E+{3,6,9}? That is fair and scientifically rigorous to state, isn't it?

Comment: I believe that I solved it by changing from windows machines to ubuntu machines. Here are the numbers - on windows machines, when L=1000 it took around 15 seconds, where on the Linux it take less than 1 second. sny idea why it's not working well with windows??

Comment: @conflux: the first call can be slow because of once-per-process initializations, can you rule that out? You can also insert tf.Print nodes to get individual timestamps and see where at which stage the slowness happens. The official version being 15x slower on windows machine sounds like a bug

Comment: Also, this slowness could be explained by [this communication bottleneck](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6116) which was supposed to have been fixed recently. You could run the toy benchmarks in the thread referenced to see if the Windows build doesn't have the fix

Answer (score -1):

### Distributed computing is our new Universe, or a set of parallel ones

A first step into this domain is always challenging. Lost certainties, that were taken as granted in monolythic computing previous experience, many new challenges, that had no similar issues in single-node process coordinations, many new surprises from new orders of magnitude of distributed execution timing- and distributed ( coordination, if not dead-lock and/or live-lock ) blocking-issues.

Thanks for added some quantitative facts ~ 15 seconds being "too-long" for `A[1000,1000];B[1000,1000];n=5` -- so far so good.

---

**Would you mind to add the above proposed code-changes and re-run the experiment on the same real-infrastructure?**

This will help the rest of this started work ( *W.I.P. here* ).

> *-- THANKS IN ADVANCE to run + post updated facts.*

---

It is hard to continue ATM with quantitatively supported statements, however, my gut feeling suspect is in this one:

```
 def matpow( M, n ):
     return  M if ( n < 1 ) else tf.matmul( M, matpow( M, n - 1 ) )
```

It uses a recursion, that may go too deep for GPU-cross-compiler/assembler analysers and given scales of tensors, the GPU SMX that are "fast" for mathematically dense-kernel microcode, the SMX-local SM_registers ( having latencies of about a **22 `GPU_CLK`s** ( well, may just 8, if smart-optimised to get fetched from well LRU-aligned SM_L1-cache-line ) will have to spill-over to global_MEMORY ( as each SM has a chance to store way less than a 1 KB in repetitive memory-access latency-most-friendly SM_Registers, but matmul() does never re-use any cell of a matrix so latency-hiding will never pay less than each global_MEMORY access + the `[PSPACE]` scales .. ), where suddenly experience about a **600+** `GPU_CLK`s latency penalties.

[While this **narrated animation of HPC `matmul()`**](https://youtu.be/JzNpKDW07rw) mentions typical CPU / Lx-cache / Memory hierarchy, the message why any **`O(N^3)`** processing must get incredibly slow on GPU-s for **`N`** going larger than could fit onto SM_registers is yet easily visible ( and as you see it, imagine all your cache-friendliness lost in recursion `matpow()` ).

GPU-kernels get best results for small-scale still-SM-local-convolutions ( where right this SMX-locality allows for good [Data:SMX-local SM_REG] alignment ( and zero cross-SMX-communication need to take place ( which is not the case in matmul() processing anywhere larger than just ~ 7 x 7 matrices, that could fit on SM_REG-silicon and anything above this has to start super-smart stencil-aligned gymnastics, if striving pay the minimum necessary sum of just-GPU-local memIO-latencies ( an the story goes forwards, if poor host2dev / dev2host IO-takes place, and many more places, where the execution-performance is uncontrollably poor ) ).

The latency costs even for a single `matmul( A, A )` are suddenly hell-loooong, of compared to typical image-specialised kernels.  ( Sure, there are advanced techniques, how to by-pass this specialised-silicon limits, but even if `matmul()` would have been a master of top tier HPC-block-matrix-ops, it will be lest as a `naive-matmul()` once recursive calls get on the stage -- that will kill even the smarted tricks, as there is no **`[SPACE]`** for the "stack"-intermediate-values, for which the auto-generated-kernel-code will pay in immense `[TIME]` penalties .. even for such small scales, like 1000x1000 ).

```
   Category                     GPU
   |                            Hardware
   |                            Unit
   |                            |            Throughput
   |                            |            |               Execution
   |                            |            |               Latency
   |                            |            |               |                  PTX instructions                                                      Note 
   |____________________________|____________|_______________|__________________|_____________________________________________________________________|________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
   Load_shared                  LSU          2               +  30              ld, ldu                                                               Note, .ss = .shared ; .vec and .type determine the size of load. Note also that we omit .cop since no cacheable in Ocelot
   Load_global                  LSU          2               + 600              ld, ldu, prefetch, prefetchu                                          Note, .ss = .global; .vec and .type determine the size of load. Note, Ocelot may not generate prefetch since no caches
   Load_local                   LSU          2               + 600              ld, ldu, prefetch, prefetchu                                          Note, .ss = .local; .vec and .type determine the size of load. Note, Ocelot may not generate prefetch since no caches
   Load_const                   LSU          2               + 600              ld, ldu                                                               Note, .ss = .const; .vec and .type determine the size of load
   Load_param                   LSU          2               +  30              ld, ldu                                                               Note, .ss = .param; .vec and .type determine the size of load
   |                            |                              
   Store_shared                 LSU          2               +  30              st                                                                    Note, .ss = .shared; .vec and .type determine the size of store
   Store_global                 LSU          2               + 600              st                                                                    Note, .ss = .global; .vec and .type determine the size of store
   Store_local                  LSU          2               + 600              st                                                                    Note, .ss = .local; .vec and .type determine the size of store
   Read_modify_write_shared     LSU          2               + 600              atom, red                                                             Note, .space = shared; .type determine the size
   Read_modify_write_global     LSU          2               + 600              atom, red                                                             Note, .space = global; .type determine the size
   |                            |                              
   Texture                      LSU          2               + 600              tex, txq, suld, sust, sured, suq
   |                            |                              
   Integer                      ALU          2               +  24              add, sub, add.cc, addc, sub.cc, subc, mul, mad, mul24, mad24, sad, div, rem, abs, neg, min, max, popc, clz, bfind, brev, bfe, bfi, prmt, mov
   |                            |                                                                                                                     Note, these integer inst. with type = { .u16, .u32, .u64, .s16, .s32, .s64 };
   |                            |                              
   Float_single                 ALU          2               +  24              testp, copysign, add, sub, mul, fma, mad, div, abs, neg, min, max     Note, these Float-single inst. with type = { .f32 };
   Float_double                 ALU          1               +  48              testp, copysign, add, sub, mul, fma, mad, div, abs, neg, min, max     Note, these Float-double inst. with type = { .f64 };
   Special_single               SFU          8               +  48              rcp, sqrt, rsqrt, sin, cos, lg2, ex2                                  Note, these special-single with type = { .f32 };
   Special_double               SFU          8               +  72              rcp, sqrt, rsqrt, sin, cos, lg2, ex2                                  Note, these special-double with type = { .f64 };
   |                                                           
   Logical                      ALU          2               +  24              and, or, xor, not, cnot, shl, shr
   Control                      ALU          2               +  24              bra, call, ret, exit
   |                                                           
   Synchronization              ALU          2               +  24              bar, member, vote
   Compare & Select             ALU          2               +  24              set, setp, selp, slct
   |                                                           
   Conversion                   ALU          2               +  24              Isspacep, cvta, cvt
   Miscellanies                 ALU          2               +  24              brkpt, pmevent, trap
   Video                        ALU          2               +  24              vadd, vsub, vabsdiff, vmin, vmax, vshl, vshr, vmad, vset
```